# Is there a notation for the region bounded by a Jordan curve (and higher-dimensional analogues)?

Tags: general-topology

If we have a subset $S$ of a topological space $X$, then its boundary is denoted by $\partial S$. But is there notation to go the other direction? For instance, in $X=\mathbb{R}^2$, if we have a simple closed contour $C$, then the Jordan curve theorem ensures that $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus C$ has two connected components, commonly called the interior $I$ (which is bounded) and the exterior $E$ (which is unbounded). Is there any precedence in the literature for a notation for these sets in terms of $C$? In general, if $C$ is a closed $n$-manifold (or even simply the image of $S^n$ under an injective, continuous mapping) in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, is there a notation for the $(n+1)$-dimensional region bounded by $C$?

Comment: You can always make up your own notation, when no standard notation exists, and use the Jordan curve theorem to justify your notation. For example "Let $D$ be the closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ which is the union of $C$ and the interior $I$ of $C$, and so by the Jordan curve theorem we have $C = \partial D$."

Answer (score 0):

Some people use the notation $int(C)$ (the "interior" of $C$), for the open region on $R^2$ bounded by the Jordan curve $C$, see for instance [Carsten Thomassen, "The Jordan-Schonflies Theorem and the Classification of Surfaces"](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/jordan/thomass.pdf). I do not particularly like this notation, but I do not think there is a better one.