# Is there a mathematical notation for the region enclosed by a set of curves

Tags: notation

I want to define the region $S$ as the area enclosed by the curves $C_1, C_2, C_3, C_4$ as in the picture below, but do not know what notation to use.
Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Suppose these [three colourful things](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Borromean_Rings_Illusion.png) are curves (circles) in a plane, and you devise a name – which one of the three shapes would it apply to?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no standard notation for this.  Best to say it in words.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The blue path is the *boundary* of $S$, denoted $\partial S$. We cannot define an inverse operator $\partial^{-1}$ to apply to this boundary so as to recover $S$, because $S$'s complement $S^\complement$ has the same boundary, i.e. $\partial S=\partial S^\complement$. However, you can disambiguate which set with the given boundary is intended. An important generalization of your example is the [interior of a Jordan curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_curve_theorem), which [has been discussed here before](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2176197/56861). In one notation, $S=\operatorname{int}(\partial S)$ (see e.g. p.4 [here](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/jordan/thomass.pdf)). (As to whether that notation serves your needs, we should address an ambiguity in your question: $\operatorname{int}(\partial S)$ doesn't include $\partial S$ itself, but $\overline{\operatorname{int}}(\partial S):=\partial S\cup \operatorname{int}(\partial S)$ does.)

Comment: Thanks, it's very helpful.